# Adobe AIR - Fullscreen / Display

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Windows computer running AIR.

Every night the educational displays get turned off.  The computers stay on.

On certain displays when they turn them on in the morning the screen resolution goes back and forth a few times starting at 1920 x 1080 then to 1024 x 768 then back to 1920 x 1080.

When this happens for some reason the AIR app freaks out and stays at 1024 x 768 which doesn't take up the fullscreen and you can see the desktop.  We have to manually relaunch the AIR app.

Is there a way when this happens we can detect and go back to force Fullscreen?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a maximized window, you can listen for `Event.RESIZE` on the stage (dispatched when the window get's resized), and or listen for the native windows `displayStateChange` or `resize` events.

If you are using the FULL_SCREEN (or FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE) display state, you can listen for the `FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN` event to know when that has changed.

Here is an example of a few things you can try:

```
//in your document class or main timeline, listen for the following events:

stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE, windowResized);
//the above will fire anytime the window size changes, Really this is all you need as this event will fire when the window display state changes as well.

stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent.DISPLAY_STATE_CHANGE, windowResized);
//the above will fire anytime the window state changes - eg. Maximized/Restore/Minimize.  This likely won't trigger on a resolution change, but I've included it anyway

stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullscreenChange);
//the above will fire whenever you enter or leave fullscreen mode (stage.displayState)
```

---

```
private function windowResized(e:Event):void {
    //re-maximize the window
    stage.nativeWindow.maximize();

    //OR Go to full screen mode
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
}

private function fullscreenChange(e:FullScreenEvent):void {
    if (!e.fullScreen) {
        //in half a second, go back to full screen
        flash.utils.setTimeout(goFullScreen, 500);
    }
}

private function goFullScreen():void {
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BFAT!  I was trying something similar but wasn't getting any event fired.  I will take a crack at your implementation.  And this will always go to the full resolution of what ever the computer/screen are set at?

Comment: It will, BUT, it's hard to know exactly what will happen in your exact scenario.    Are use the FULL_SCREEN display state? or Just a maximized window?  (you can also listen for the stage's display state change to know when you've been booted out of fullscreen, which might be more reliable if you're using fullscreen)

Comment: Do comment with your results after trying this.   If it doesn't work, try adding a couple second delay after the event before attempting to re-maximize or re-fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks BFAT for throwing this up.  This coupled with the timer seemed to do the trick.  I added another second onto the timeout since one of the screens takes forever to toggle.  Im electing to buy a new display.